# Chat with php and ajax with bug design css

Tags: css, chat

I work in a new project, I´m doing the "chat part" a one-to-one chat.. with php and ajax.

I´m new of css stuff.. while I was testing the code, I found a problem:
The text does not go down and continues skipping over design, I put an image for better understanding.

[image: Testing]

The css code:

```
.login_form {
border: 1px solid #AAA;
padding:10px;
}
h3 {margin-top:3px;}
.chat_main {
border:1px solid #AAA;
-moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
width:350px;
padding:10px;
background:#f3f3f3;
}
.message {
border:1px solid #AAA;
margin:4px;
padding:5px;
-moz-border-radius:7px;
-webkit-border-radius:7px;
background:#ffffff;
}
.textf {-moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px #CCCCCC;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px #CCCCCC;
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
height:40px;}
.submit {
-moz-border-radius:7px;
-webkit-border-radius:7px;
background:#F3F3F3;
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
font-size:16px;
font-weight:bold;
height:35px;
margin-left:10px;
padding:5px;
}
.message span {
font-size:10px;
color:#888;
margin-left:10px;
}
.submit_form {
margin:10px 0px;
}
```

Hope u can help me, I think it´s a simple error design that I don´t know because I´m new in design stuff.

Comment: no idea what you area asking

Comment: Fixed, thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use exact words instead of spam words like `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` this is not a word that why you are facing this issue.

Even If you want to use like this then you can use `overflow-wrap: break-word;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `word-break:break-all;` property **or** `word-wrap:break-word;` property:

For example :

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid #CCC;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```